# cwac-loaderex: How to get inserted row ID?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

When using the `insert()` method of the `SQLiteCursorLoader` class, is there a way to get the row ID that was returned as a result of the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not presently. I'll look to add that support someday via a callback. Right now, what you can do is subclass `SQLiteCursorLoader` and override `insert()`, supplying your own clone of `InsertTask` that holds onto the row ID and does something with it, perhaps from `onPostExecute()`.